# Is it “près de” or “près à”, is there a difference?

Tags: prépositions, indications-de-lieu

Which is correct and why?

> Léo habite près de chez Barbara.

or

> Léo habite près à chez Barbara.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

« Près à » est incorrect.

« Près de » est une locution prépositive signifiant « À proximité de » à prendre d'un bloc.

Comment: Merci M42, dans votre réponse c'est interessant le phrase ''prendre d'un bloc''. Pour moi 'prendre un bloc suffit'. Pouvez vous me expliquez, comment on utilisé "d'un bloc" contre "un bloc"?

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora: I mean "Take it as a whole".

Comment: That I understand, thank you for explanation. My question is why you use "d'un bloc" as against "un bloc". Could you also say  "à prendre comment un bloc"?

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora:« À prendre d'un bloc » is the right way to say.

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora to make it clear, "prendre un bloc" means literally "take a block", whereas "prendre d'un bloc" means (figuratively) "take as a whole"

Answer (score 2):

## Près de

« Près de » est une locution signifiant qui indique la proximité géographique ou temporelle.

> J'aime être près de toi.

Dans un sens un peu plus spécialisé, un nombre peut-être proche d'un autre :

> La tour Eiffel est haute de près de 325 mètres.

Il y a aussi l'expression « *être près de ses sous* » qui signifie être avare.

Pour la proximité temporelle :

> Il est près de 13h, allons déjeuner !

## Prêt à

« *Près à* » est incorrect, mais ce prononce exactement de la même façon que « *prêt à* » qui signifie être disposé à, être en état de.

> Dans une relation amoureuse, il faut être vraiment prêt à tout. Un bonheur est si vite arrivé ! (Jacques Salomé)

> Veux-tu acheter des (vêtements) prêt-à-porter ?